# Efficient Method to do Calculations on Joint Distributions in R

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, covariance, correlation

If I have the following joint distribution where the top row is the value of Y and the first column on the left are the values of X, what is the most efficient/clean way of going about calculating the covariance and correlation between X and Y?

I was thinking of loading each row into a new variable and just doing the necessary calculations and then running the cov() and cor() functions, but I know there has to be a better way?

Thanks!

---

```
|   |  14 | 22  | 30  | 40  | 65  |
|---|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| 1 | .02 | .05 | .10 | .03 | .01 |
| 5 | .17 | .15 | .05 | .02 | .01 |
| 8 | .02 | .03 | .15 | .10 | .09 |
```

---

Comment: Have a look at library(mvtnorm) and library(sos)

Answer (score 1):

You should most definitely use matrix multiplication to get the results. The following is probably not the *most* efficient way, but it uses the formulas in a straightforward way.

```
# input data
yvec <- c(14, 22, 30, 40, 65)
xvec <- c(1, 5, 8)
jp   <- matrix(c(.02, .05, .10, .03, .01,
                 .17, .15, .05, .02, .01,
                 .02, .03, .15, .10, .09),
                 nrow=length(xvec), ncol=length(yvec), TRUE)

Ex  <- rowSums(jp) %*% xvec    ## E(X)
Ex2 <- rowSums(jp) %*% xvec^2  ## E(X^2)
Vx  <- Ex2 - (Ex)^2            ## Var(X)
Ey  <- colSums(jp) %*% yvec    ## E(Y)
Ey2 <- colSums(jp) %*% yvec^2  ## E(Y^2)
Vy  <- Ey2 - (Ey)^2            ## Var(Y)
Exy <- xvec %*% jp %*% yvec    ## E(XY)

(Cxy <- Exy - Ex*Ey)           ## covariance
(Rxy <- Cxy /sqrt(Vx * Vy))    ## correlation
```